# Selfclosing anchor replication

Tags: html, ckeditor

Why **CKEditor** (v3.6.1) parse selfclosing anchor and wrap all with that anchor?

Example: `http://jsfiddle.net/JF4j9/`

This portion of HTML:

```
<p><a id="JD_CPCART48" name="JD_CPCART48"/> <b>Artículo 48º.- Finalidad.-</b>   </p>
<p>Las funciones ...</p>
<p><a id="JD_CPCART49" name="JD_CPCART49"/><b>Artículo 49º.- Organos judiciales en el área civil.-</b></p>
<p>La justicia civil es ejercida ...</p>
```

get transformed into this:

```
<p><a id="JD_CPCART48" name="JD_CPCART48"> <strong>Art&iacute;culo 48&ordm;.- Finalidad.-</strong> </a></p>
<p><a id="JD_CPCART48" name="JD_CPCART48"> </a></p>    
<p><a id="JD_CPCART48" name="JD_CPCART48">Las funciones ...</a></p>    
<p><a id="JD_CPCART48" name="JD_CPCART48"> </a><a id="JD_CPCART49" name="JD_CPCART49"> <strong>Art&iacute;culo 49&ordm;.- Organos judiciales en el &aacute;rea civil.-</strong> </a></p>    
<p><a id="JD_CPCART49" name="JD_CPCART49"> </a></p>
<p><a id="JD_CPCART49" name="JD_CPCART49">La justicia civil es ejercida ...</a></p>
```

Why? How can I tell to CKEditor that a selfclosing `A` is a selfclosing `A` and no wrap all content into anchors.

I don't want to modify the source HTML to fix selfclosing `A`, I need to make this with CKEditor

Answer (score 2):

Anchor element does not allow selfclosing, so your html is invalid and i'm pretty sure the browser is causing what you're describing.

selfclosing tags include (but not limited to): hr, br, input, meta in head and so on.

If you are looking for ways to manipulate input or output through ckeditor, you should hook into their dataprocessor. Docs here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor

A related SO article describes that very well here: [CKEditor 4 Images and dataProcessor API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143494/ckeditor-4-images-and-dataprocessor-api)

You can hook into any element and decide exactly how you want them to come in or out. It's a somewhat different question and you need to write some code and make an attempt before i can help you further.

Comment: What I want to know is, If I can fix that with CKeditor to save the fixed html into DB.

Comment: short answer, yes, you can do that. I updated my answer with a few links to get you started.